# I don't understand roots of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers

So I'm aware that $z = a + bi = r(\cos(m) + i\sin(m))$

But this is where my confusion starts. Suppose $z^n = 1$.

My lecture notes say $z^n = r^n(\cos(nm) + i\sin(nm))$ by De Moivre's theorom. Ok fine but, how does:

$|z| = r$. So, $|z^n| = r^n$.

make sense? Doesn't $z^n = r^n(\cos(nm) + i\sin(nm))$? Where's that bracket gone? This topic has really stumped me.

Edit: Ignore me, I didn't see why $r^n$ became 1. Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two expressions you've written for $z^n$.

Comment: No, that I understand but how come |z^n| = r^n

Comment: Note that $|\cos(nm)+i\sin(mn)|=1$.

Comment: Do you understand how to draw $a+bi$ in the plane? Do you understand why $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$?

Comment: @C-RAM that's what I was trying to get at. Why is that bracket 1?

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes I understand the complex plane and why r, the 'hypotenuse', is that but I think I understand now. I didn't see why why r^n became 1 but now I do

Comment: Good. Also not that $a+bi=\frac{r}{r}(a+bi)=r(\frac{a}{r}+\frac{b}{r}i)=r(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the real axis and the complex number.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes exactly. I have 1 more question if I may. Now cos(nm) + isin(nm) = 1 by De Moivre's theorem. Why is the real part cos(nm) = 1 and the imaginary part sin(nm) = 0?

Comment: The cosine is the real part and the sine is the imaginary part. You can see this if you view the complex plane as a vector space where the real axis is like the $x$ axis and the imaginary axis is like the $y$ axis. There is a missing piece which is Euler's identity. We can use the Taylor series expansions of the sine, cosine and exponential functions to show that $e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$. Now, $(e^{i\theta})^n=e^{in\theta}=\cos{n\theta}+i\sin{n\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|z| = r$ because $|z| = \sqrt{(rcos(\theta))^2 + (rsin(\theta))^2} = \sqrt{r^2}$

But $z = r(cos(\theta) + isin(\theta)) $ is still true.

Similarly by de Moivre if $z^n = r^n(cos(n\theta) + isin(n\theta))$ then $|z^n| = r^n$ is also still true.

The modulus of a complex number (the |.|) is not the same as the complex number itself.

Let me know if this doesn't clarify what you were confused about.

Comment: That's it. I feel like my confusion is too simple when posting here and I feel like im wasting people's time

Comment: @TingoHugo Don’t be discouraged! I remember being confused about roots of unity when I first learnt it. Complex numbers are a very different concept to other topics one does at school (algebra, geometry etc.) This platform is here to help people, of all levels.

Comment: @TingoHugo So ask away

Answer (score 3):

It is a general property of complex numbers that $|\cdot|$ is *multiplicative*, i.e. that
$$|zw|=|z|\cdot|w|$$
if $z,w\in\mathbb C$. One can prove this by the definition in terms of coordinates. Suppose $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$. Then $zw=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$ and
\begin{align*}
|zw|&=\sqrt{(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{a^2c^2-2acbd+b^2d^2+a^2d^2+2adbc+b^2c^2}\\
&=\sqrt{a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2}\\
&=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}\\
&=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot\sqrt{c^2+d^2}\\
&=|z|\cdot|w|.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

The alternatve proof to the one in the answer of Carl Shildkraut, which applies to all non-zero Complex numbers is:

Any non-zero Complex number $z$ of the form 
$t [\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)] ~: ~t \in \Bbb{R^+}$ 
will have

$$|z| = \sqrt{ ~[ ~t\cos(\theta) ~]^2 + [ ~t\sin(\theta) ~]^2 } = t.$$

Assume that

- $z = r \times [\cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha)].$
- $w = s \times [\cos(\beta) + i\sin(\beta)].$

Then $|z| \times |w| = r \times s.$

Also,

$$z \times w = r \times s \times  \\
\\ \left\langle ~\left\{ ~[\cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta)] - [\sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta)] ~\right\} \\
+ i ~\left\{ ~[\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)] + [\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)] ~\right\} ~\right\rangle $$

$$= (r \times s) \times \\
\\ [ ~\cos(\alpha + \beta) + i\sin(\alpha + \beta) ~].$$

Set $t = (r \times s)~~$ and 
set $\theta = (\alpha + \beta).$

Then

$$|z \times w| = | ~t \times ~[ ~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta) ~]  ~| = t = r \times s = |z| \times |w|.$$

Comment: @lonestudent I don't consider it an injustice.  First, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236), and then ask yourself whether it is unreasonable for MathSE to want the missing information provided. ...see next comment

Comment: Well, Thank you for points. So not everyone agrees.  I know about references.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @lonestudent I see nothing unreasonable about asking the poster to supply : [1] Their Math background. [2] The background of the problem. [3] What tools (as described in the article) does the poster think *might* be relevant. [4] Exactly what work has been attempted.  Here, the poster is supposed to detail all of the efforts that they have made, in a well organized way.  It is irrelevant whether they solved the problem.